# load .txt file into gridview c#

Tags: c#, gridview, load, text-files

So im nearly there, just need to load the information from my text file in notepad which is saved like so:

item1

item2

item3

item4

My first attempt was this:

```
gridProfiles.Columns.Add("App Name", "Active");
        int i = 0;
        foreach(char snif in "D:\\ProfileAppName.txt")
        {
            gridProfiles.Rows.Add();
            gridProfiles.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = snif;
            i++;
        }
```

But this just loaded the file name into the text file

My next attempt was:

```
 gridProfiles.Columns.Add("App Name", "Active");
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string snif in "D:\\ProfileAppName.txt")
        {
            string[] values = snif.Split(' ');
            int j = 0;
            foreach (string value in values)
            {
                gridProfiles.Rows.Add();
                gridProfiles.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = snif;
                j++;
            }
        }
        i++;
```

But i get the error "cannot convert type 'char' into 'string'

Can anyone help me? im nearly there but cant get my finger on it

Answer (score 0):

You are looping all chars in this string: `"D:\\ProfileAppName.txt"`. I assume you want to loop all lines in the file. Then you can use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx):

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("D:\\ProfileAppName.txt"))
{
    gridProfiles.Rows.Add();
    gridProfiles.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = line;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: that worked like a treat.. Will mark correct soon, Only thing now is that, it all loads into 1 column, i need it to load into multiple columns. Any Idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The read the content of the file you could do this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(string row in File.ReadAllLines("D:\\ProfileAppName.txt"))
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        gridProfiles.Rows.Add();
    gridProfiles.Rows[i / 2].Cells[i % 2].Value = line;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to the other persons, also works, it loads into 1 column, anyway to make it load into multiple columns?

Comment: I dont see any columns in your file example.  Are the columns separated in any way?  Please give a better file sample if you want more help.

Comment: the only way ive been able to save textboxes into the text file is single like that going down the page, so unless There is a way to save them in a row/line?

Comment: Do you mean that each row is a column? I don't understand.

Comment: ok so basically this part of my program consists of a few textboxes that save into a .txt file.. but when they save. they save in a list going down the page not next to each other. It worked so they all loaded into the first column. but i need every second one to load into the second column of gridview and the first one to load into the first column of the dgv

Comment: I have corrected the answer to your new requirements. The changes adds a new row at line 0, 2, 4,... and inserts every even line in column 0 and odd line in column 1.