# How to bind data from txt file to gridview C#?

Tags: c#, text, gridview, row, col

As checking some article about this, I find at the reference below [load .txt file into gridview c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468026/load-txt-file-into-gridview-c-sharp) . But it seems not the same which I want to do, transfer data from row to column. I have a text file like this (about 6 rows)

```
1010
Apple
Fruit
15
$10
Gala, Green
```

I will binding it to gridview with the following six columns: `ID, Name, Category, Qty, Price, Remark`.

I tried the below code:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo("file_data.txt");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line != "")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_data.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                dgv_data.Columns[i].ToString() = line; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice for this and what should I do for better results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a datasource that you can assign to the DataGridView.Datasource property.

Let's create a class for Fruit.

```
class Fruit 
{
  public string ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Category {get;set;}
  public string Qty {get;set;}
  public string Price {get;set;}
  public string Remark {get;set;}
}
```

Then create a method that reads lines from any textreader, keep track of the read state and assign the line to the correct property of the current Fruit instance. Store each instance in a list of Fruit.

```
List<Fruit> GetFruits(TextReader reader)
{
    string line;
    var rowCount = 0;
    
    Fruit currentFruit = null;
    var fruits = new List<Fruit>();
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        switch(rowCount) 
        {
            case 0:
                // create a new Fruit
                currentFruit = new Fruit();     
                // keep this fruit
                fruits.Add(currentFruit);
                // populate our currentFruit instance
                currentFruit.ID = line;
                break;
            case 1:
                currentFruit.Name = line;
                break;
            case 2:
                currentFruit.Category = line;
                break;
            case 3:
                currentFruit.Qty = line;
                break;
            case 4:
                currentFruit.Price = line;
                break;
            case 5:
                currentFruit.Remark = line;
                // reset state
                rowCount = -1;
                break;
        }
        rowCount++;
    }
    return fruits;
}
```

Putting it together:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file_data.txt"))
{
     dgv_data.DataSource = GetFruits(sr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo("file_data.txt");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) // you are looping the lines ...
    {
        if (line != "")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_data.ColumnCount; i++) // and set _each col_ to that line value! 
                                                           // => makes no sense!
            {
                dgv_data.Columns[i].ToString() = line; // .ToString() makes no sense here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, you could make this simpler and actually work:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file_data.txt");
// if you are going async:
// var lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync("file_data.txt");

for( int i = 0; i < Math.Min(lines.Length, dgv_data.ColumnCount); i++ )
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[i])) continue; // Skips empty lines, doesn't set their column.
    dgv_data.Columns[i] = line[i];
}
```

For reference:

- [File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0)
- [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-5.0)

---

Outside of that, I'd like to recommend using some proper serialization format like XML, JSON, CSV, maybe and a respective model class.

---

**Mind**: I left `dgv_data.Columns[i] = line[i];` like this, because it is unclear what type it is.

If this is a `DataRow`, then the line should probably be `dgv_data.Cells[i].Value = line[i];`.

If it is something else, you might want to drop a comment and I'll fix the answer.

Comment: `dgv_data` is DataGridView , the code below not working `for( int i = 0; i < Math.Min(lines.Length, dgv_data.ColumnCount); i++ )
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line[i])) continue; // Skips empty lines, doesn't set their column.
    dgv_data.Columns[i] = line[i];
}`

Comment: Currently, I am busy, but I'll look into it later.

Comment: can not assigned value each lines to each column.

Comment: this row `dgv_data.Rows.Add.Columns[i] = lines[i];`  maybe the structure not defined which lines fill-up to which columns in DataGridView.

Comment: As is, it would just go along the index. line[0] goes into col[0] , line[1] to col[1] ...

Comment: yes, that's I want to do, as above can get line by lines, just need to transfer line[i] to col[i] now.

Comment: Oh, ... please try this: instead of the for-loop, just do this : `dgv_data.Rows.Add(lines);`

Comment: OMG!, data can transfer from row to col, but it is a loop, six rows same value, I try to change `dgv_data.Rows.Add(lines[i]);` but six rows in first column, funny

Comment: Nono, I meant: replace the whole loop by that one line.